# I want to install Java JDK 8 on mac, but .bash_profile won't detect JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to get Java JDK 8 on my mac. I'm currently running the newest, update to date version 10.0.2 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.
I tried to nano .bash_profile and export the command

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

and then source .bash_profile and it says:

```
-bash: usr/libexec/java_home: No such file or directory
```

I tried googling and searching here, but nothing helped so far :/

Comment: Try `/usr/libexec/java_home`, note the initial `/`

Comment: Wow. Incredible rookie mistake, thanks alot. Been googling for like 1 hour just to see I made a typo

Comment: No worries. Given that that was the issue, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path to `java_home` is relative and hence cannot be found by your bash script. Try using:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Note: the initial `/` makes it an absolute path.